# Update query instead of select + save

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

Is it possible with JPA using play framework to execute an UPDATE sql query?

For the moment what I do to make an update to an entity is:

- To retrieve the entity via the find() method or a select query in the find() method
- Change the value I want
- call the save() method on the object

But I guess it makes 2 queries: a SELECT and an UPDATE.

Is there a way to do everything using only one query? Only an UPDATE query?

Thank you for your help

Comment: doesn't merge() API on the entity manager work in playframework? Merge API might be doing the same thing under the hood, but it would at least relieve the user from running those steps.

Comment: @Vikdor But isn't there a way to make only an UPDATE query ?

Comment: Since you are dealing with entities managed by the entity manager, it's the manager who decides how to update the entity you supplied through the merge API. You can find the exact behavior discussed in "Putting all together" section at http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/23/jpa-implementation-patterns-saving-detached-entities/.

Comment: @Vikdor so there is no real way to make only an UPDATE query ?

Comment: afaik, No from an entity manager perspective. You just call the merge and it will take care of performing the appropriate action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're using the API methods, I don't think you'll get around your 2-queries problem. The entity manager can't just start updating entities. It has to find them first, check their state and then decide if an update is really necessary, i.e. if changes were made or not.
You could however, always write your own parametrized update statement using `JPQL`. Your `find()` will most likely use an id or something similar, which matches the primary key of your entity.
 
You could just pass the id into the statement and update directly. I would only do this however, if the id isn't coming from user input but rather from a previous select. In other words, guaranteed to be an existing entity and the one you really want.
The query could look something like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyValue = :newValue WHERE MyId = :id
```

Where you pass in newValue and id as a parameter.

However, I would rather let the entity manager do all the work. Why do you want to do it in a single statement anyway? Unless you're doing a ton of the operations, speed shouldn't be a problem as these short and specific statements are usually quite fast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wanted to have only one query to increase speed and don't overload the mysql server but if it is not really important I will continue with my 2 queries

Comment: @FabienHenon Do you **need** to increase speed? Or are you trying to optimize away an issue that's not really there? I'm not saying that speed can't be a problem with this. It really depends on the structure of your database and the scale of your operations. Unless you're updating on a larger scale, you can most likely ignore the difference in speed.

Comment: Ok. Speed is not so important for the moment but I was just trying to anticipate for the future. If you say the difference in speed can be ignored I trust you